# Umbraco MVC4 IntelliSense not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco, intellisense

I'm working on a few Umbraco projects that use MVC4. The MVC intellisense doesn't work within visual studio and I get lots of errors underlined. But when I run build the project, I don't get any errors, and when I run the site everything works fine.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and I created a new MVC4 site and compared the web.configs within the Views folder and they're identical.

I'm pretty sure it's not a code problem as my colleague is using the same code and he doesn't have this problem.

I've just done a fresh install of Visual Studio 2013.

Any ideas?

This could be a clue:
When I hover over `@Html`it tells me that my HtmlHelper is a `System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper` instead of a `System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper`

Comment: Try to Unload your Project in VS, and then add it again in your solution. Right click on your project and select Unload Project.

Answer (score 0):

The common one is to ensure that it is switched on (Visual Studio menu: Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages (or C# if you want it *just* for that language) > Tick "Auto list members", Untick "Hid advanced members", tick "Parameter information")

Once you've checked this, sometimes if you're using one HDD on Windows, because the disk has its bandwidth used up (particularly if using ReSharper then you need two or more drives ideally with the pagefile going to the non-OS drive I find). This is the case if the red lines do disappear after up to two minutes of not touching the IDE.

Finally check you project's *references* folder to make sure where the paths for your includes are coming from and that Visual Studio has permission to read from there. Permission issues cause all manner of problems I find, so when you launch VS, right click and choose "run as Administrator".

Hopefully one of these solves your problems. If not, then please update your question to explain how you create your project. Do you create an empty site or an MVC site? Do you then use Nuget to install Umbraco through the Package Manager Console like this?

```
Install-Package UmbracoCms
```